# Configure Service Fabric TCP listener to listen on more than 1 port

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

We have a native TCP/IP C/S technology we want to port to Azure SF Cluster; the server application listens on 3 ports once the client is connected and registered. We have written TCP/IP listener and we can specify a singular port and we are able to make the first primary connection over the specified port recorded in the SF manifest; however, once the client connects two other connections are made to the service over ports specified by the server at runtime. The first connection to the server will return data to the client and contains information for the client to make other connections on ports allocated by the server. Is there a way to configure SF Listener to observe more than one port?

Answer (score 0):

See if you can create 3 separate communication listeners, each listening on 1 port. In this case, SF would manage the dynamic port number, so you can use service discovery etc.

If that's not an option, just open ports outside of the SF reserved port ranges; usually above application port range (30000) and below the start of the ephemeral port range (49152). In this case, you'd manage the additional ports inside the single communication listener. You'll need to come up with a way to share the information about which ports were opened and a way to deal with port conflicts.

Comment: thanks! I will give this a try and get  back to you

Comment: I did try your suggestions and it did not work. After months of experimenting with assistance from Azure SF support and an outside vendor, I was told that what I wanted to do was not technically possible at this time. Looks like SF is mostly relegated for RESTful/HTTP development. Very disappointing.